# Passing payloads to vcloud vms

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, payload, jclouds

I am going to use jclouds to manage the vcloud IAAS. Is there a way that we can pass some payload/data (say some key-value pairs) vcloud machines when we create the VM s?

I am pretty much happier with the "user data" mechanism of Amazon Ec2 [1]

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

Answer (score 2):

Use a vCloud [Customization Script](http://pubs.vmware.com/vcloud-director-1-5/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=user/GUID-724EB7B5-5C97-4A2F-897F-B27F1D4226C7.html) to create a file with whatever extra data you need.

To set the customization script you will need to set the customizationScript in the template options. Something like this should work:

```
ComputeServiceContext context = // get the context
TemplateBuilder builder = context.getComputeService().templateBuilder();
// set the builder options here

Template template = builder.build();
TemplateOptions templateOptions = template.getOptions();
VCloudTemplateOptions vcloudTemplateOptions = (VCloudTemplateOptions)templateOptions;
vcloudTemplateOptions.customizationScript(YOUR_SCRIPT_HERE)
context.getComputeService().createNodesInGroup("MY_GROUP", 1, template)
```

See additional template options for vcloud here: [VCloudTemplateOptions](http://javadocs.jclouds.cloudbees.net/org/jclouds/vcloud/compute/options/VCloudTemplateOptions.html)

Comment: I am more comfortable with the user data solution in Amazon EC2 [1]. Is there any solution similar in vcloud?
[1]http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

Comment: You can try adding metadata in userMetadata() in the template options. Not sure if this is passed to the vCloud as VM metadata. If so, you can use the REST API to get the metadata from your VM - http://www.vmware.com/support/vcd/doc/rest-api-doc-1.5-html/operations/GET-VAppMetadata.html but note that this API requires authentication.

Comment: Lets say I set metadata somehow,but how can I access these metadata from inside the VM since I need the username/password to retrieve the metadata.How can I pass the username/password to the VM.

Comment: Since you need to authorize the metadata API call, you need to pass the credentials to the VM somehow. A customization script is probably the best way to pass data to the instance.